# Whats the key value in the Cache populated via @Cachable

Tags: spring, caching, ehcache

I have a cache thats populated via @Cacheable   as follows

```
    @Cacheable(value = "accountGroupCache")
public List<Acc> getAccInfo(int groupId, String user)
```

I would like to know what will be the key value pair for this cache? I am using ehcahe to do the caching.

Answer (score 0):

The key will be based on the parameters to your `getAccInfo()` method.  The value is going to be the `List<Acc>` returned by your method.

According to the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-default-key):

> 28.3.1.1 Default Key Generation
>
> Since caches are essentially key-value stores, each invocation of a
>   cached method needs to be translated into a suitable key for cache
>   access. Out of the box, the caching abstraction uses a simple
>   KeyGenerator based on the following algorithm:
>
> - If no params are given, return 0.
> - If only one param is given, return that instance.
> - If more the one param is given, return a key computed from the hashes of all parameters.

Looking at the source code for [DefaultKeyGenerator](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/springframework/spring-context/3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE-sources.jar!/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/DefaultKeyGenerator.java?format=ok), this is how it computes "a key computed from the hashes of all parameters":

```
    int hashCode = 17;
    for (Object object : params) {
        hashCode = 31 * hashCode + 
                          (object == null ? NULL_PARAM_KEY : object.hashCode());
    }
```